# MySql table columns are automatically adding with existing columns

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I have a spring boot application. And I configured my MySql Database table with 3 fields in the DAO Layer. After starting my application this table creating without problem. But after sometime it gets adding 2 more fields with underscore. Please find the below table.

```
CREATE TABLE `sample` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contractId` varchar(20) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  `customerName` varchar(50),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

After sometime the table is having below fields.

```
id
contractId
customerName
contract_id
customer_name
```

Why last two columns are adding without doing anything?

Can anyone please help on this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete these columns :

```
ALTER TABLE sample
 DROP COLUMN contract_id;
 DROP COLUMN contract_name;
```

Comment: Hi Witzig Adrien, Thanks for your response. I can do that. But it's keep on adding for every restart of my application. Is there any change needed from application side or table creation side or MySql Engine side?

Comment: Do you use PHPMyAdmin ?

Comment: No. I am using MySql Workbench

Comment: Okay so in your code, I supposed that you create the Table every time you run your code. You need to run your script one time because if you create the table several times, SQL will create columns if he can.

Comment: Or delete the table at the end of your script

Comment: I am using below script for DB schema creation if it's not existed.
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mySampleDb;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210579/discussion-between-naveen-goud-and-witzig-adrien).